# Как заставить GrpcChannel использовать HTTP/2 на MonoAndroid?

Tags: c#, android, mono, grpc

Я пытаюсь выполнить запрос к моему серверу по [MagicOnion](https://github.com/Cysharp/MagicOnion) (он использует транспорт от gRPC, но другой протокол сериализации, *message pack* вместо *protobuf*).

Небольшой тестовый клиент, запускающийся под `net5.0` выполняет примерно такой код:

```
AppContext.SetSwitch("System.Net.Http.SocketsHttpHandler.Http2UnencryptedSupport", true);
var address = $"http://{ServerUrl.Host}:5002";
using var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress(address);
var myServiceClient = MagicOnionClient.Create<IMyService>(channel);
var result = await myServiceClient.GetMyData();
```

...и успешно получает ответ. Однако когда я пытаюсь выполнить в точности такой-же код на Android, я вижу такую ошибку в логе сервера:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http2.Http2ConnectionErrorException: HTTP/2 connection error (PROTOCOL_ERROR): Invalid HTTP/2 connection preface.
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http2.Http2Connection.ParsePreface(ReadOnlySequence`1& buffer, SequencePosition& consumed, SequencePosition& examined)
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http2.Http2Connection.TryReadPrefaceAsync()
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http2.Http2Connection.ProcessRequestsAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)
```

По логам и дампу трафика видно что клиент на .Net 5 использует `HTTP/2`, а на Android - `HTTP/1.1`. На сколько я могу понять, это единственная разница между двумя запросами.

Как сделать так, чтобы клиент на Android (API 30, monoandroid10) использовал всё же `HTTP/2`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60362990/12888024

Comment: @aepot ох, жаль. Напишите ответ о том что это невозможно сделать?

Comment: Почему же невозможно? Быть может просто надо другие библиотеки использовать. Я сам не в теме. И тот пост прошлогодний, с тех пор все могло поменяться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение состоит в том чтобы использовать другую библиотеку с реализацией `GrpcChannel` - **Grpc.Core**.
В моём случае она сразу не заработала, я получил ошибку связанную с загрузкой `libgrpc_csharp_ext` Чтобы она заработала в Xamarin, нужно так же подключить **Grpc.Core.Xamarin** той же версии, что и Grpc.Core. `MagicOnionClient` отлично работает с `GrpcChannel` из этой библиотеки.

Вот так выглядит рабочий пример:

```
var channel = new Grpc.Core.Channel(ServerUrl.Host, 5002, Grpc.Core.ChannelCredentials.Insecure);
var myServiceClient = MagicOnionClient.Create<IMyService>(channel);
var result = await myServiceClient.GetMyData();
```